# generate multiple view layout in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create multiple `View` layout programmatically and add theme into another layout, in java do that was simple but in kotlin when i try that run time error happens!

my code is:

```
fun generateAnswersStatus(){

        //@drawable/ui_top_rounded_answer_background_correct

        for(q in match_game!!.getQuestions()!!){


            val v = View(this)

            v.id = q.getId()!!
            v.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(30,40)

            lytAnswerStatuses.addView(v)

            if(q.getUser1Answer() == null){

                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ui_top_rounded_answer_background_normal)
            }else{

                if(q.getUser1Answer()!!.toInt() == q.getCorrectAnswer()){

                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ui_top_rounded_answer_background_correct)
                }else{

                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ui_top_rounded_answer_background_wrong)
                }

            }

            lytAnswerStatuses.addView(v)
        }

    }
```

and error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding your `View` to its parent twice, you have this call duplicated in your code:

```
lytAnswerStatuses.addView(v)
```

Simply remove one of the calls to avoid the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding View "v" to the layout before if condition and doing it again after the if condition. So when you are adding it again to the layout after the if condition, your View 'v' already has a parent as it was attached to your layout previously.

So to handle this:
You remove one of the 'addView' statements or just remove the parent from view to which it is attached before adding the view second time. with

*((ViewGroup)v.getParent().getParent()).removeView((ViewGroup)v.getParent());*